# Python docx Lib Center Align image

Tags: python, image, center, docx

I'm building a automated report program using https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

I'm trying to center a picture and even tried this trick that I read somewhere on google:

`document.add_picture('C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Picture.jpg',height=Inches(3.44))
last_paragraph = document.paragraphs[-1]
last_paragraph.style = 'centerstyle'`

with no luck...

Anyone out there figured out a way to get around this?

Answer (score 43):

You could do something like this.

```
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH

my_image = document.add_picture('path/to/image') 
last_paragraph = document.paragraphs[-1] 
last_paragraph.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
```

I know I am probably replying to late now but maybe it helps to somebody else.

Comment: Yes, it certainly did help at least one somebody else, thanks for the effort!

Comment: This did help me. Thank you! 

Comment: Me too, should have been marked as the answer. Nit pick: No need to define `my_image` variable.

Comment: Had to use WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT but worked the same.